# sql - how to know the row number from certain id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sorry for the title. I'm so confuse what title should i write. Editing my question title is allowed.

i have this url : **example.com?id=33**

thats mean: **SELECT content FROM article WHERE id=33**

content id 33 will shown in thats page.

but, in the footer i want to give pagination. because id=33 is the 17th row. the pagination will be

**15 16 [17] 18 19**

the problem is:

how to know the row number of id 33?

Comment: Rows doesn't really have a row number... it all depends on the order you apply to your table...

Comment: thanks @JordiNebot . but my friend tells me the answer via Whatsapp second ago. i will post the answer

Comment: Or the `ORDER BY` that you apply to your query to be more precise

Comment: This might be what you want? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Comment: the answer is : SELECT count(*) FROM article WHERE id <=33

Comment: thanks for everyone. i appreciate for your attention and help.

Comment: Well its an answer, but probably not to the question asked

Comment: You should still `ORDER BY id` otherwise you will get rows back in an indetermiate order

Comment: i see. thanks @RiggsFolly